# flask mod_wsgi apache windows redirect error

Tags: windows, flask, mod-wsgi

I have a problem with mod_wsgi and flask on Windows 10.
When I start app from console with "flusk run" it's work,
but from apache I've got an error INET_E_REDIRECT_FAILED

Here is my directory structure:

- E:\www\test.wsgi
- E:\www\test\app\__init__.py

test.wsgi:

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, 'E:/www/')

from test import app as application
```

__init__.py:

```
    from flask import Flask
    
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.debug = True 
        
    @app.route('/')
    @app.route('/index')
    def hello_world():
        return 'Hello Flask under Apache!'
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run()
```

apache.conf:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /test "E:/www/test.wsgi"
<Directory "E:/www/test/">
 WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
 AllowOverride none 
 Require all granted
</Directory>
```

get from apache access.log:
`"GET /test/ HTTP/1.1" 308 262`